# Логирование в консоль Catch2

Tags: c++, catch2, catch-unit-test

Почему `Catch2` не логирует сообщения? В пустом `TEST_CASE` пишу `INFO("42");`. После запуска в консоли получаю:

> ========================================================================= test cases: 1 | 1 passed
>
> assertions: - none -

Куда делся лог?

**upd:**

Макросы `UNSCOPED_INFO` и `CAPTURE` также ничего не выводят. Если добавить какой-нибудь `REQUIRE` или флаг `-s`, опять таки в выводе только резултаты тестов и никаких логов. Единственный лог из проверенных, который работает, это `WARN`.

Версия 2.9.2, репортер `console`.

Comment: Возможно, связано с этим багом https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/1759

Answer (score 1):

Логи не показываются если тест прошел успешно,
более того, `INFO` не показывается если ошибка произошла в другом scope.

https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/logging.md#logging-macros

Используйте `UNSCOPED_INFO`.

Comment: Я попробовал и `UNSCOPED_INFO` и `CAPTURE` -- всё равно не выводит. Выводит только `WARN`

Comment: Да и с флагом `-s` для успешных тестов тоже не показывает

Answer (score 0):

Выводятся сообщения из `INFO()`, `UNSCOPED_INFO()` и `CAPTURE()` только **до сфейлившего** теста.

Выведет все сообщения:

```
INFO("1");
UNSCOPED_INFO("2");
CAPTURE("3");
CHECK(2 == 3);
```

Выведет первые 2:

```
INFO("1");
UNSCOPED_INFO("2");
CHECK(2 == 3);
CAPTURE("3");
```

Не выведет ничего:

```
INFO("1");
UNSCOPED_INFO("2");
CHECK(3 == 3);
CAPTURE("3");
```